# How to force Visual Studio to use specific Android Emulator?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, android-emulator, xamarin.android

I have a question about Android Emulator(s) (well, there are actually three sub questions). So, In VS2015 we have two Emulators installed:

[image]

On the left - built in Visual Studio Android Emulator (made by Microsoft), using Hyper-V (please correct me if I'm wrong)

On the right - built in.. Xamarin.Studio? Android Emulator (made by Android), using HAXM (please correct me if I'm wrong).

I have a problem, because when you create a Xamarin.Forms project you get this Virtual Device setup by default:
[image]
It uses API19, but when I click "Run", it's complies without errors and deploy/run in new Android Emulator (on the right). Why?
When I open Android Virtual Device Manager, selects the same virtual device and click "Starts", it opens the Android Emulator (on the left). Why?

I've enabled Hyper-V for now, my Windows emulators work.

**How can I force Visual Studio to run on old "on the left" Android Emulator when I run the project? Can I set this up?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open your **Android Emulator Manager** you will find the following choice

[image]

x86 means AVD with HAXM. If you do not have that choice please install image with HAXM

[image]

The emulator that create by android emulator manager is **Google's default emulators**, and **Your left side emulator** that means the Google's default emulators and with the skin like "WQVAG" or someting others.

**Your right side emulator** that is created by vistual studio:

[image]

when you find the the **CPU Architecture is x86** that means it works with HAXM

[image]

**Use the different AVD Name will clearify which emulator you selected to run.**

> How can I force Visual Studio to run on old "on the left" Android Emulator when I run the project? Can I set this up?

Select the emulator that create by **android emulator manager** with the skin.
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure I understand though. 1) You said "x86 means AVD with HAXM" - but there are 4 position you marked on 2nd screenshot, 2 of them has "64" in their name. Are they 32bit or 64bit? 2) You said "Google's default emulators, and Your left side emulator", but two x86 cpus has "Google" in their name too, and yet they are create by Visual Studio?

Comment: 1) 64 means the image is 64 bit compatible with 64-bit operating systems.
2) I said the emulator that create by "android emulator manager" is google default emulator. That means the images in 2nd screen shot are all google default emulator. And the "Google APIs x86..." means the image with google service API such as google map api and google push api,

Comment: @IshThomas You can open **android emulator manager** by  **tools-->android-->android emulator manager**

Comment: @IshThomas in conclusion the image created by **tools-->android-->android emulator manager** is google default emulator. And the image that created by **tools-->Visual Studio Emulator for Android** is visual studio emulator

Comment: Mia Thanks again. But If I create an AVD here (tools-->android-->android emulator manager) with cpu set to Intel Atom x86. It will still run Visual Studio emulator (on the right). Correct?

Comment: When you create an AVD you will named it. You can chose the emulator you named using the **small down arrow** (not the green run arrow).

Comment: @IshThomas I have edit my answer with "how to chose the emulator you created".

Answer (score 0):

**On the left** is an `AVD` thus it is Google's default emulators. It could be HAXM accelerated if you installed HAXM.

**On the right** is the VS Emulator for Android created by the Visual Studio team.

You are confusing the built in AVD emulators with the VS Android emulator.

By default whichever `Device` is selected **(Has the green play button next to it)** will be used. In your case, you have the **VS Emulator for Android** selected and thus it will always deploy to that one.

You can use the small **down** arrow to select another compatible emulator such as the Google emulators if you created a new AVD that is compatible with your project.

**See further:** https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/android-sdk-emulator/

Comment: so which one works only with HAXM (without HAXM running it will crush)? Also, you said "In your case, you have the VS Emulator for Android" - how do you know? Where? When I open **Android Virtual Device (AVD) Manager** click Create, I have only: Device, Target, CPU.. there is no info where to deploy.